# Very slow function

Tags: c++, strtol

strtol is very slow for my program which I want it to be very fast

so for example I have this string:

```
PCHAR ex = "\x55\xEC" etc...
```

They're hex, so If I want to write it without the "\x" to be like "55 EC" etc.. I have to use strtol, but strtol is EXTREMELY slow for my program I want the fastest one on my program..

```
I use strtol like (CHAR)strtol(ex, &ex, 16);
```

Mind helping me please?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Display your array without the 0x prefix?

Comment: Does that compile for you? Passing `&ex` as the second parameter makes no sense when `ex` is an array.

Comment: Oh sorry It is `PCHAR ex = "\x55\xEC";`

So what I want to do is: type the hex char without the \x

so it would be: `PCHAR ex = "55 EC"` 

and after that using the alt of strtol changes it to `\x55\xEC`

Comment: If I now understand your question, I guess you could speed up your program by first converting the text pattern to binary and use the binary for pattern matching as you did before.

Comment: so i would convert the "55 EC" to binary and continue? but wouldn't it be still the same as it will convert the "55 EC" to binary and not convert the "55 EC" to "\x55\xEC"?

Comment: "\x55\xEC" is the binary representation of "55 EC", that's why I wrote "use the binary for pattern matching as you did before"

Comment: So, I still don't know how to convert it to binary xD

Comment: Just pass it to strtol, but do it only once and not each time while parsing your data `for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) { bin_p[i] = std::strtol(p, &p, 16); }` or using `std::istringstream` for a more c++ like solution.

Comment: I already said strtol is really slow, that's why I want to stop using it

Comment: strtol is not that slow.  The program that you showed in the link is slow because you convert it over and over again.  converting the pattern of around 20 hex values is too fast to notice if you only convert it once and use the result of that for pattern  matching.  Try timing a single conversion of a pattern.

Comment: check this new discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757747/findsignature-function

I made my own implented strtol which is getByte but still having some issues you may help me on

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
unsigned long ex[] {0x55, 0xEC};

  for (auto i : ex)
    std::cout << std::hex << i << " ";
```

Output is: `55 EC`

Comment: You got me wrong, I want the input like "55 EC" and convert it to 0x55 and EC to 0xEC

strtol is doing it correctly, but its really slow taking like 6 seconds or 5 to get it, while I want it to be really fast

Comment: @Frought: no, you are wrong: the input in your question is "\x55\xEC", not "55 EC".  These strings are completely different and actually is a different question. `char ex[] {0x55, 0xEC, 0};` is the same as `char ex[] = "\x55\xEC";`

Comment: About strtol taking 5 to 6 seconds, you could provide us with a working example that shows this.  That would help to spot the problem.

Comment: I'm doing that inside my pattern finder function aka signature finder:

http://privatepaste.com/f19f997e61/5000

pasetkey is 5000

CC is a wildcard

so the usage would be: `FindSignature("55 EC CC A1", baseAddress, size, mLength);`

rather than: `FindSignature("\x55\xEC\xCC\A1", baseAddress, size, mLength);`

Benchmarked my pattern and it took like 6 ~ 5 seconds with strtol, while without strtol it (using \x55etc..) took around 200ms

Comment: So you were not actually wrong, but very unclear.  I guess most of us didn't understand that you want to change the input form "\x55..." to "55..." which doesn't help getting an answer.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But I'm still finding anything faster or even some idea

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying? `strtol` converts a byte string to a long integer; when the string has `0x` as prefix it treats the string as hexadecimal number. It won't convert `\x55` into `55`. Three errors in assumption:

- It will convert `0x55` into `55`. No, it'll convert it into `85` (decimal)
- It will convert multiple numbers in a string. No, it'll convert just one number in a string to a `long` or `long long`)
- It will take a hex number of the format `\x`. No, this should be `0x` for it to recognize it as a hex value

What you have is not a use case of `strtol` at all. You'll have to manually do the conversion.

All you need is to just a find-replace of all `\x` with space and trim the resulting string to shave off the leading space.

Comment: I want to convert the 55 itself to 0x55 ^^